# Text indexing library in C/C++

Tags: c++, indexing, information-retrieval

I am developing a Windows desktop product which requires text indexing library in C/C++. I would want to give it series of words and a record that needs to be stored against those words. Searching those words should bring back one or more records quickly. Data will be stored on disk.

I have searched this forum and found Lucene. But it is basically Java. There is a CLucene C++ port also. But I am not sure if it is suitable (light weight?) for a small Windows desktop product.

I have found other .net based libraries but not something light weight and for C++.

Can you help please?

Comment: What you want is _trie_, I think. You can study it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). There are some links to `C++` implementations there.

Comment: How many words? records?

Comment: Is the word set dynamic?  Would you add or remove any new words?

Comment: Do you need partial matches on words?  Would "chat" come back if I searched for "hat"?

Comment: @Tom Kerr: It is a file search utility. The records would be as many as files on an average computer. Unique words would be less than records, as new words would be added & removed, for now we are allowing word matches. But would prefer to have partial match capability also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)?  A RDBMS might be a little heavy, but I believe that it is used inside of some web browsers to implement HTML5 "Local Databases".

Comment: If the search space wasn't huge or they didn't need to partial matches this would certainly work.